# How to exchange data between forms in C# , without cause conflict?

Tags: c#

I am trying to exchange data between forms, but that causes conflicts in opening tabs, or even lose that data when I pass through pages/forms..

I had tried different methods, some are changing the name in labels in those forms (from button of login), but had conflicts in opening pages in between and than losing that data.

Comment: What UI technology are you using? The answer will differ between ASP.NET and UWP, for instance. [Edit] your question to include the appropriate tag.

Answer (score -1):

You can make a static global string so that you can use this in any forms

Create a new class

```
public MyClass
{
   public static string GlobalString = string.Empty;
}
```

Usage

```
String getValue = MyClass.GlobalString;
```

Set

```
MyClass.GlobalString = newVaue;
```

Comment: Might be good advice for a static state medium (like Winforms) where gets and sets might be less liable to things like multiple threads setting the field at the same time. Bad advice for ASP.NET and anything multithreaded...

Comment: Well if using ASP we can use `LocalStorage`

Comment: What bout winforms, u think is a problem doing exchange of data in between..

Comment: You can try my codes above

Comment: In WinForms you should be using property binding. Then value changes propagate. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/data/overview